# PHP abstract classes and protected methods

Tags: php, design-patterns, abstract, protected

Like title say I have a problem with this code:

```
abstract class AClass {
    abstract protected function a1();
    abstract protected function a2();

    public function show() {
        return $this->a1() . "<br>" . $this->a2();
    }
}


class A1 extends AClass {

    protected function a1() {
        return 'A1a1';
    }

    protected function a2() {
        return 'A1a2';
    }
}

class A2 extends AClass {

    protected function a1() {
        return 'A2a1';
    }

    protected function a2() {
        return 'A2a2';
    }
}

class AA {

    public function __construct() {
        $a11 = new A1();

        $a22 = new A2();

        $this->inter($a11);
        $this->inter($a22);
    }

    private function inter(AClass $class)  {
        echo $class->show();
    }
}

$aa = new AA();
```

It is throwing:

> Fatal error: Call to protected A1::a1() from context 'AA' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Learning\index.php on line 38

Line 38 is this:

```
$a11 = new A1();
```

I do not understand why it is throwing that error if I'm not calling a1() at that line.

Thanks and regards

Javier

Comment: Are you using one of the few php versions that support constructors named from the class?  http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: I'm using PHP Version 5.6.20 it looks that it support them, does it?

Comment: From your code it appears so. What kind of constructor behavior do you want?

Comment: I'm testing abstraction, so with these I want to test the protected methods called by a public no abstract method from the parent class of the two implementations. But I don't know why at the A1 constructor A1(); is calling the a1() function, if I'm not modifying the A1 constructor nether the AClass constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At line 38 you make an instance of class A1, so the constructor is called: it is the `function a1()` on line 15. Since class names are case-insensitive, so are constructor names, too.

Since your constructor is protected, it cannot be called from outside of the class. Maybe you can make a public static function, call that without instantiation, and inside of it you can  call the constructor. It can be good for the Singleton class design pattern.

If you want to test only the abstraction with normal methods, simply rename your functions, so they will not be constructors.

Comment: Thank you man that was the problem, I did not know about case-insensitive of constructors.

Comment: @GezaBoehm Hats off for this answer. +1.